# terms asymptotically equal?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that $\left ( \frac{k-i+1}{k}\right )^{j}$ and 
$\left ( \frac{k-i}{k}\right )^{j}$ are asymptotically equal when k is large enough, 
$1\le i\le Q$ and $Q$ is a constant.

Could you please give me indications about that?
Thanks

Comment: $j$ is fixed, and the asymptotic equality is for $k\to\infty$?

Comment: if $j$ is fixed, then just divide them

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

$$\left(\frac{k-i+1}{k}\right)^{j}=\left(1+\frac{-i+1}{k}\right)^j$$

$$\left ( \frac{k-i}{k}\right )^{j}=\left(1-\frac{i}{k}\right)^j$$

As $k\to\infty$, can you see why the two expressions are asymptotically equal?

Answer (score 0):

First Note that
$$(\frac{k-i+1}k)^j=(\frac{k-i}k+\frac{1}k)^j$$
And by binomial theorem:
$$(\frac{k-i}k+\frac{1}k)^j=(\frac{k-i}k)^j+\binom{j}{1}(\frac{k-i}k)^{j-1}(\frac{1}k)^1+\binom{j}{2}(\frac{k-i}k)^{j-2}(\frac{1}k)^2...$$
Given that $K$ is large enough,$\frac{1}k$ is close to $0$, so all terms but the first cancel.