# limit of an expression?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Actually what I'm really looking for is the proof of the following limit:

$\frac{\left [\left ( \frac{k-i+1}{k}\right )^{j} - \left ( \frac{k-i}{k}\right )^{j}  \right ]}{\sum_{i=1}^{Q} \left ( \frac{k-i+1}{k}\right )^{j} - \left ( \frac{k-i}{k}\right )^{j}}$

as k is large enough, where $j$ is fixed and $1 \le i \le Q$ with $Q$ constant.

In the original proof, they just say the limit is $\frac{1}{Q}$, but no details are given.

Is there any indication please?

Thanks

Comment: Finding the limit as $k\to\infty$ of this expression is the same as asking if they are asymptotically equal to each other, as you already did in your previous post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990304/terms-asymptotically-equal/990322.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Divide numerator and denominator by $k$ and you then have $$A=(1-\frac {i-1}{k})^j-(1-\frac {i}{k})^j$$ and apply the binomial theorem.

For the very first terms, you should arrive to $$A=\frac{j}{k}+j\frac{-2 i j+2 i +j-1}{2
   k^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^3\right)$$

I am sure that it was obvious to you that expanding the powers in the original expressionswill remove the $k^j$ which stays in the denominator.